# How to show the equivalence between the natural number set, and the subset of the integer set which behaves like the natural number set?

Tags: analysis

This question might a bit long-winded to ask. 
Let's say we define the natural number set $\mathbb{N}$ using set theory as follows: 
$0 = \emptyset \\
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}(S(n) = n \cup \{n\}).$ 
So that by this definition and ZFC, the Peano axioms can be derived.

Then define addition and multiplication on $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$:

$n +_\mathbb{N} 0 = n \\
m +_\mathbb{N} S(n) = S(m +_\mathbb{N} n)$

$n \times_\mathbb{N} 0 = 0 \\
n \times_\mathbb{N} S(m) = (n \times_\mathbb{N} m) +_\mathbb{N} n$

After that, we define the integer set $\mathbb{Z}$ by defining an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$((a, b) \sim (c, d)) \Leftrightarrow (a +_\mathbb{N} d = b +_\mathbb{N} c)$. 
Then, the integer set can be defined as the set $\mathbb{Z} = \{[(a, b)] | a,b \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $[(a, b)]$ is the equivalence class of $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

And additon and multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined, using their respective operations for $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$: 
$[(a, b)] +_\mathbb{Z} [(c, d)] = [(a +_\mathbb{N} c, b +_\mathbb{N} d)] \\
[(a, b)] \times_\mathbb{Z} [(c, d)] = [((a \times_\mathbb{N} c) +_\mathbb{N} (b \times_\mathbb{N} d), (a \times_\mathbb{N} d) +_\mathbb{N} (b \times_\mathbb{N} c))]$

Then, we can notice a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\{[(a, 0)] | a \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which behaves exactly like $\mathbb{N}$. This should be obvious as it is intuitive for $\mathbb{Z}$ to contain $\mathbb{N}$.

Finally, the question I would to ask is that how to prove the "equivalence" between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{[(a, 0)] | a \in \mathbb{N}\}$; that is to say, how to prove that for all true statements about the natural number, they will be applicable for $\{[(a, 0)] | a \in \mathbb{N}\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$? And that what does it mean for all natural number $n$, the integer $[(n, 0)]$ can be "identified" with $n$? 
For example, how do I prove that for statement like $(1 +_\mathbb{N} 2 = 3) \Rightarrow ([(1, 0)] +_\mathbb{Z} [(2, 0)] = [(3. 0)])$ or that $\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}(((a +_\mathbb{N} b) +_\mathbb{N} c = a +_\mathbb{N} (b +_\mathbb{N} c)) \Rightarrow (([(a, 0)] +_\mathbb{Z} [(b, 0)]) +_\mathbb{Z} [(c, 0)] = [(a, 0)] +_\mathbb{Z} ([(b, 0)] +_\mathbb{Z} [(c, 0)])))$ (the assciatiative property of addition)?

The ideas I have is to define a "successor function" for $\mathbb{Z}$, $S_\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (S_\mathbb{Z}([(n, 0)]) = [(S(n), 0)])$. Then show that the structure $(\{[(a, 0)] | a \in \mathbb{N}\}, [0, 0], S_\mathbb{Z})$ obeys the peano axioms just like the structure $(\mathbb{N}, 0, S)$. As the peano axioms implies all these true propositions of the natural number, they must also be true for these integers.

Any help will be appreciated. If there is any expressions in my post that can be improved, please point them out.

Comment: Not quite sure what you ask but the set of statements (and therefore the set of true statements) is countable since every statement has finite length.

Comment: If you can show that the set in question satisfies the Peano axioms then it will be equivalent to the naturals. So you're on the right track here.